# Remotly syncing NAS behind routers I don't have access to

Tags: ssh, router, rsync, network-attached-storage

We have several NAS (WD My Could Mirror) that travels to multiple cities and are fed locally with images, audio, video, etc.

This content needs to be synced to our main office.

I am trying to use rsync with ssh for that.

Here is the main issue : we don't have the ownership of/access to the routers that the NAS are behind and those routers as the locations of the NAS change frequently.

So the only solution I see now is to set a cronjob on the machine to sync from automatically to our office. However I don't have any access to the machine in the case where something goes wrong.

Is there any solution that would allow me to sync the machine's content without doing port forwarding on the router?

Thanks

Comment: Talk to the people having NAS with them.

Comment: I do, but that doesn't change the fact that neither I nor them have access to the router

Comment: I don't understand: why can't you have a cronjob inside the NAS that rsyncs to your Office server?
Anyway, i would look into making the NAS call home via OpenVPN or autossh+supervisord